# Height funtion for $(this) object doesnt respond in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, height, this

I'm trying to get the height of a DOM object but it doesn't show the actualy height. If you refer the below example, the height always some default number on IE8 compatibility view, but on firefox it shows dynamic values.

```
    $("div.span3").each(function() {
        var he = $(this).height();
        if (he > hie) {
            hie = he;
            highestempty = $(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So if there are 4 div.span3 elements and one comes out the max height as 150, firefox displays proper but IE8 shows 125 for all. Its like its not doing the work intended to. Please help!

Comment: Just curious what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: version : jquery 1.10.1

Comment: This happens on IE8 compatibility view. Please help !

Comment: is there any chance you can force your page to render in standards mode by adding this to the head tag? `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;IE=10;IE=9;IE=8,chrome=1"/>` if so it will make so much of your web development easier.